# How does Amazon prevent mischief in their AWS Lambda service if I am allowed to execute code on their machine?

Tags: server, aws, countermeasure

AWS Lambda lets me execute a piece of code on a random Linux machine it provides to me, whenever I need to run my code.

What is stopping me from executing OS level commands that let me take over the machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply, the environment within which you are executing your commands is sandboxed and is unable to affect the host OS or other users' commands. Unless there's a vulnerability, of course. From https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/:

> Q: Can I access the infrastructure that AWS Lambda runs on?
>
> No. AWS Lambda operates the compute infrastructure on your behalf,
>   allowing it to perform health checks, apply security patches, and do
>   other routine maintenance.
>
> Q: How does AWS Lambda isolate my code?
>
> Each AWS Lambda function runs in its own isolated environment, with
>   its own resources and file system view. AWS Lambda uses the same
>   techniques as Amazon EC2 to provide security and separation at the
>   infrastructure and execution levels.

Answer (score 3):

AWS Lambda is powered by FireCracker, a micro-vm technology that basically sandboxes your code from the actual underlying machine, and other users' functions. You can read more about FireCracker here: https://firecracker-microvm.github.io/